# How to encrypt and decrypt message RSA in python?

Tags: python, rsa

I am trying to write RSA encryption and decryption in python without Crypto library and in short I have generated  public(e,N) and private(d,N) keys to exchange with message and I don't know how to that.The message I want to send is also key:`b'gAAAAABenIFsZD5Oa7GPNKPV7yBHSKasuzpMzYPPoXbEqX3cbxO_9-3eP9UdKOXsrQmLSesKkaeKk9VZXI6Qx-iWS8tglsxbRwjgdAWPZKQa8NLyH1ICKJgEihrc-9ybO6WgV_jASgHH0zg4mdEP8XhxQmg6-S96HA=='`

Does someone know how to encrypt message with my public key and decrypt it with private ?

```
import random



def gcd(a, b):  # gdc to find proper e
    if (b == 0):
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b, a % b)


def isPrime(num):
    if num > 1:

        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                return False;
                break
        else:
            return True

    else:
        return False;


def pGenerator():
    p = 0
    while p == 0:
        pn = random.randint(0, 40)
        if (isPrime(pn)):
            p = pn
            break

    return p


def qGenerator(p):
    q = 0
    while q == 0:
        pn = random.randint(0, 40)
        if (isPrime(pn) and pn != p and pn <p):
            q = pn
            break

    return q


def eGenerator( fiN):
    e = 0

    while e == 0:
        pn = random.randint(0, fiN)
        if (gcd(pn, fiN) == 1):
            e = pn
            break
    return e


def start():
    p = pGenerator()
    print(p)
    q = qGenerator(p)
    print(q)

    N = p * q
    fiN = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
    print(fiN)
    e = eGenerator(fiN)
    d=multiplicative_inverse(e,fiN)
    c=encrypt(e, N, "d")
    decrypt(d,N,c)
    print(c)

def encrypt(e,n, plaintext):
    #Unpack the key into it's components
    key=e

    #Convert each letter in the plaintext to numbers based on the character using a^b mod m
    cipher = [(ord(char) ** key) % n for char in plaintext]
    #Return the array of bytes
    return cipher
def multiplicative_inverse(e, phi):
    d = 0
    x1 = 0
    x2 = 1
    y1 = 1
    temp_phi = phi


    while e > 0:
        temp1 = temp_phi / e
        temp2 = temp_phi - temp1 * e
        temp_phi = e
        e = temp2

        x = x2 - temp1 * x1
        y = d - temp1 * y1

        x2 = x1
        x1 = x
        d = y1
        y1 = y

    if temp_phi == 1:
        return d + phi


start()
```

Comment: You don't "exchange" your private key, that defeats the entire purpose of RSA in particular and encryption in general. *...Does someone know how to do that ?...* Are you asking if someone knows how to send am encrypted message? The same way as you send an unencrypted message. If you want more specific help please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk Thank u, changed and " exchange" part will be later because my problem now to encrypt message  and decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [rsapy](https://pypi.org/project/rsapy/)?
Just read its docs on its PyPI page.

Example:

```
import rsapy
pub, pri = rsapy.genkey(2**512)
print(rsapy.encode("message", pub))
# This also works with b"message"
```